# How to select records without duplicate column in mysql

Tags: mysql

My Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `opd`;

OPD No | Name
---------------
1      | Ravi
2      | Ravi
3      | Ravi
1      | Ravi
4      | Ravi
5      | Ravi
2      | Ravi
```

I want the result using mysql query or any other method to the following:

```
OPD No | Name
---------------

3      | Ravi
4      | Ravi
5      | Ravi
```

Kindly note I dont want distinct column I want to remove all duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT OPD_No, Name
FROM opd
GROUP BY OPD_No, Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```